# tmux server does not use /tmp/tmux-<userid>/defaut, can't list nor attach session

Tags: sockets, pipe, tmux

When doing the following

1. launch a tmux session named "x11"

> ```
> tmux -S x11
> ```

Detach

> ```
> CTRL-B d
> ```

List available sessions:

> ```
> tmux list-sessions
> ```

I get the following error

> ```
> kalou@shinwey:~$ tmux list-session
> no server running on /tmp/tmux-1000/default
> ```

May someone explain what is happening here ?

tmux server is running

> ```
> kalou@shinwey:~$ ps -efa | grep tmux
> kalou     2172     1  0 17:40 ?        00:00:00 tmux -S x11
> ```

tmux is using a "pipe", not a socket

> ```
> tmux:\x20 2172  kalou 3r  FIFO               0,12  0t0 32527 pipe
> tmux:\x20 2172  kalou 4w  FIFO               0,12  0t0 32527 pipe
> tmux:\x20 2172  kalou 6u  unix 0x00000000c2777ccb  0t0 32528 x11 type=STREAM
> ```

How may I force tmux server to use a "socket" ?

How may I force tmux server to use a "pipe" ?

The doc talks about a /tmp/tmux-/default socket ...

Would be very happy about any feedback on this question

Best Regards

Comment: Ok I connection to socket sucessful using parameter -S /tmp/tmux-<userid>/default.Usually we don't need this. Why here ?

Answer (score 1):

*Every* use of `tmux` looks at the default socket unless told otherwise.

```
% tmux -S x11  # attaches to a new session, then I detach
[detached (from session 0)]
% tmux list-sessions
no server running on /private/tmp/tmux-501/default
% tmux -S X11 list-sessions
0: 1 windows (created Thu May 14 12:52:48 2020)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok the good syntax to launch a tmux session is

> ```
> tmux new-session -s <session-name>
> ```